# How to use event in Custom Property?

Tags: python

I have a custom property `prop` and I want to use event `Ctrl` and `Alt` for increment similar to collection `hide_render`.

[image]

[image]

```
import bpy


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Demo"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.prop(context.scene, "prop")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.types.Scene.prop = bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        name = 'Test',
        description = '* Ctrl to increment of 5\n* Alt to increment of 10',
    )


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.prop


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Is it possible?